# How to reshape/ format data table - take common text in column and make new row as sub header

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, formatting, flextable

The below is an example of my df

```
structure(list(Name = c("Barry ", "Lisa"), Height = c("182 cm", 
"151 cm"), Hair = c("Black", "Red"), Mood = c("80% good 10% bad", 
"90% good 10% bad"), Grades = c("Math:45GPA English: 60GPA History: 40GPA", 
"Math:50GPA English: 60GPA History: 45GPA"), Behavior = c("Good: 60%", 
"Good: 75%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

it will look like:

```
    Name Height  Hair             Mood                                   Grades Behavior
1 Barry  182 cm Black 80% good 10% bad Math:45GPA English: 60GPA History: 40GPA Good: 60%
2   Lisa 151 cm   Red 90% good 10% bad  Math:50GPA English: 60GPA History:45GPA Good: 75%
```

I want to take common text in the column and make it a new row to act as sub header to the table . For certain columns this may also include splitting 1 column into 2 or more columns, not a requirement though.

```
    Name Height  Hair    Mood          Grades          Behavior <----- overall header
1            cm       good bad   Math English History    Good %  <----- sub header
2 Barry  182    Black   80  10     45      60      40        60  <---- data
3   Lisa 151      Red   90  10     50      60      45        75
                 ^1 col unchanged            ^
                                             ¦Col split into 3 new columns (if required)
```

Is there a function or package capable of doing this? I realize I may need to spit it out and edit in excel after but if I could get that far I would be happy.
I have looked at gt and Kable but I cannot quite get what I want out of it. My actual df  has special characters including decimal places, ^, / , >/= and μ.

Comment: have a look at flextable, notably here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/layout.html

Comment: the data structure is not *tidy*, that make things harder. Do you have the source of the data you are showing?

Answer (score 0):

So using the flextable package as suggested above I can do the below, Is there a more streamline approach possible?

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Barry ", "Lisa"), Height = c("182 cm",                       "151 cm"), Hair = c("Black", "Red"), Mood = c("80% good 10% bad",                                                                                                   "90% good 10% bad"), Grades = c("Math:45GPA English: 60GPA History: 40GPA",                                                                                                                                         "Math:50GPA English: 60GPA History: 45GPA"), Behavior = c("Good: 60%",                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Good: 75%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- df %>% mutate_all(str_replace_all, c("cm"), "") %>%
  mutate_all(str_replace_all, c("good"), "") %>%
  mutate_all(str_replace_all, c("bad"), "") %>%
  mutate_all(str_replace_all, c("Math:"), "") %>%
  mutate_all(str_replace_all, c("English:"), "") %>%
  mutate_all(str_replace_all, c("History:"), "") %>%
  mutate_all(str_replace_all, c("GPA"), "") %>%
  mutate_all(str_replace_all, c("Good:"), "") 

names1 <- c("Name", "cm", "Colour", "Mood", "Grades", "Behaviour")
colnames(df2) <- names1

df2 <- df2 %>% separate('Mood', c("Good", "Bad"), sep="\\s\\s") %>%
 separate('Grades', c("Math", "English", "History"), sep="\\s\\s")

ft <- flextable(df2)
ft <- add_header_row(ft, values = c("","Height", "Hair", "Mood", "Grades", "Behaviour"), 
                     colwidths = c(1,1,1,2,3,1))

print(ft)
```